# Linq - OrderBy int column gives incorrect results

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query which gives me Incorrect results. I want to `Order By first Year` & then `By Month`. So My results should be `Jan 2015, Feb 2015, Mar 2015` & so on.

```
var data = ctx.tblCalendar
                    .Where(e => e.Id == Id)
                    .OrderBy(e => e.Year).ThenBy(e => e.MonthNo)
                    .Select(e => (InputMonths)e.Month + "-" + e.Year)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();

DataType of MonthNo is int
DataType of Year is int
DataType of Month is Enum
```

The above query gives me results as `April 2015, August 2015, December 2015,Feb 2015` & so on. It is Ordering by Alphabets which is Enum.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Distinct should normally preserve order, but for an experiment you could try removing it and see if results are ordered the way you need.

Comment: What is `InputMonths`?

Comment: Note how the months are sorted alphabetically. Are you sure `MonthNo` contains a numeric value, and not the actual name of the month?

Comment: InputMonths is Enum containing MonthNames Jan, Feb, Mar,..

Comment: `MonthNo` contains number values...when i query this directly in sql it works there.

Comment: Is `data` ordered again before output? Or can you verify that the sequence in `data` itself is already wrong?

Comment: What's the difference between e.Month and e.MonthNo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [`IEnumerable<T>.Dictinct()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the returned sequence is an unordered one.

> The Distinct(IEnumerable) method returns an
>   unordered sequence that contains no duplicate values. It uses the
>   default equality comparer, Default, to compare values.

And the documentation of the [`IQuerable<T>.Distinct()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348456(v=vs.90).aspx) says the same thing, which is logical since it will be translated to whatever provider (SQL, EF) is working.

> The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression
>   tree that represents calling Distinct(IQueryable)
>   depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The
>   expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the
>   unique items in source.

The solution is to select the data you need, perform your distinct, then order your result, and finally do your projection.

Like this:

```
var data = ctx.tblCalendar
    .Where(e => e.Id == Id)
    .Select(e => new { e.Year, e.MonthNo, e.Month })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Year)
    .ThenBy(e => e.MonthNo)
    .Select(e => (InputMonths)e.Month + "-" + e.Year)
    .ToList();
```